# Is it possible to copy/export WebSphere Application Server Cell configuration from one environment to another environment?

Tags: websphere, jython, middleware, websphere-7

Remember this is not Standalone Environment.

In one physical server I have set up a Cell with one Deployment Manager, one Node, one application server and configured them. Now I need to create 12 more similar cell with same configuration in different physical servers. So is it possible to copy/export configuration from one environment to another ?

Creating the Cell is not a problem for me, I want to skip the step of configuring again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Start by looking at this IBM KnowledgeCenter [topic](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/txml_property_configuration.html?lang=en) on properties-based configuration and administration.  It has a number of links to other topics with additional information.  The property file based configuration allows you to extract a text file of properties from an existing WebSphere Application Server configuration, perform some processing on the text file (like changing hostnames, ports, etc) using your favorite tools and then apply that configuration to another cell, node, or server.